# Android Vector drawable doesn't scale for small screen height

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development, I have created a android layout for XXXHDPI screens Pixel XL 5.5 (1440 * 2560:560dpi) and Pixel 4XL (1440 * 3040:560dpi)

These two screens have height difference but dpi are the same, if I add vector assets some view ends at the bottom of the screen in pixel XL 5.5, but on Pixel 4 XL it looks okay, please check the link below for screenshot, vector asset layout_width and layout_height are wrap_content

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe6wv.png

if I change vector asset layout_width and layout_height to some dp value, Pixel XL 5.5 looks okay but in Pixel 4XL views looks small, screenshot is below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPdb6.png

Not sure how to resolve this, I guess vector assets should automatically scale down for smaller screen, the size remains the same on both screens. Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hey there this issue is common when using Linear or relative layouts with png/jpeg images , Try using constraint layouts with SVG images , heres a video on how to use constraint layouts if your are a beginner https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsgXFdynDuQ&ab_channel=LBLB

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response, I am using constraint layout and vector asset and still facing this problem.